# Get key on contextmenu click

Tags: javascript, jquery, crossrider

I am looking to get the key of the menu item which was clicked in a list of contextmenu's, does anyone know how, this is how I create the context menu:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
    appAPI.contextMenu.add("key_" + i, 'Test', function (data) {
        console.log('clicked with key: ', data);
    }, ["all"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why do you need to **get the key**? ContextMenu listeners are declared per key, so **you know which key it is**. Using your code:

```
for(var i=0; i<10; i++) {
  (function(key) {
    appAPI.contextMenu.add(key, 'Test', function (data) {
      console.log('clicked with key: ',key, data);
    }, ["all"]);
  })("key_" + i);
}
```

[**Disclosure**] I am a Crossrider employee

Comment: it is because I have a for loop which creates the menu based on a response from the API therefore I cannot hard code the listener like this!

Comment: In that case, please edit the code and show the loop.

Comment: done, just a simple for loop for demostrational purposes, but same priciple

Comment: I edited the example adding your loop and an enclosure to retain the key value.